# QProcess failed to start/execute from ProgramFiles

Tags: qt, permissions, qprocess

I'm doing a QT app for windows that during the execution I need to start another program that is on the same folder than the executable.
The thing is that I have this currently working but it only fails when I copy the folder into "C:/program files (x86)", it just doesn't execute it and neither giving any QProcessError.

For example, if I put the folder of my program (with all necessary DLL's and the other .exe) at desktop or directly in c:, it does work, but the moment it's inside ProgramFiles (x86) it stops working the part that automatically execute the second program.

I think it should be some kind of permision problem, but, my QT app asks for admin right when it's executed.

Here, the code:

```
QProcess procStart;
...
connect(procStart, SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)),this, SLOT(slotProcessError(QProcess::ProcessError)));
...

void AppName::launchProcess()
{
    procStart.start(rootPath + ressources + app);
}
```

Any idea?
I've tried with start, startDetached, execute, etc... and same result always, outside programfiles works flawlesly, but not inside.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that you're invoking the `static` member [`QProcess::startDetached`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached-2) which will create a new process and detach from it.  So listening for signals from `procStart` won't work.  Please provide a [mcve] and say *why* you need to detach the process.

Comment: @G.M. sorry, I didn't meant to use the startDetached, it was my last trial and doing copy paste without revising was my fault.
By the way, the problem of running it from programfiles persists.

Comment: `QProcess procStart;`
`procStart = new QProcess(this);` , does that really compile??!!

Comment: @MohammadKanan sorry, it was from the past edit, that i had QProcess* and startDetached, my mistake.
By the way, about the thing I'm talking, any idea? Thanks.